# Enlazar un datos de un valor a una fila específica

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código que alimenta un ajax pero al momento de insertar el array "$sqlStr2" me toma todos los valores y me los inserta en orden numérico pero el array "$nota" me lo toma con los valores que yo necesito. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo verificar para que ambos me tomen los valores que le corresponden a los arrays?

```
else if ($_REQUEST["set"] == "insertarCursos") {
    $alumnos    = explode(",", $_REQUEST["alumnos"]);
            $nota           = explode(",", $_REQUEST["notafinal"]);
    $sqlStr     = "";
    $sqlStr2    = "";
            $sqlStr4        = "";
    $sqlStr3    = "insert into uni_notas (id_curso,id_seccion,id_alumno,semestre,asistencia,zona,siglas,exfinal,notafinal,recupera,tipo,estado) values ";

    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($alumnos)) {
        $sqlStr .= "'" . trim($alumnos[$i]) . "'," ;
        $i++;
    }
            while($i < count($nota)) {
        $sqlStr .= "'" . trim($nota[$i]) . "'," ;
        $i++;
    }

    $sqlStr = substr($sqlStr, 0, (strlen($sqlStr) - 1));

    $query      = $initCore->query("select * from uni_alumnos where codigo in ($sqlStr)");
    while ($row = $initCore->fetch_array_assoc($query)) {
        $sqlStr2 .= $row["id"] . ",";
    }


    $initCore->free($query);
            $sqlStr2    = substr($sqlStr2, 0, (strlen($sqlStr2) - 1));
    $sqlStr2    = explode(",", $sqlStr2);

    $i = 0;
    while($i < count($sqlStr2)) {
        $sqlStr3 .= "(" . $_REQUEST["curso"] . "," . $_REQUEST["seccion"] . "," . $sqlStr2[$i] . ",'" . $_REQUEST["semestre"] . "',0,0,NULL,0," . $nota[$i] . ",0,'A',0),"; 
        $i++;
    }
    $sqlStr3    = substr($sqlStr3, 0, (strlen($sqlStr3) - 1));
    $sqlStr3   .= ";";

    if ($initCore->query($sqlStr3))
        echo "true";
    else
        echo "false";
}
```

Los datos que contienen los arreglos sony en ese orden lo ingreso

```
$sqlStr2: 13700049, 13700051, 16700058, 13700027, 13700001 
$notas: 75 78 68 70 70
```

Y este es el orden el que me los inserta:

```
13700001    75 
13700027    78 
13700049    68 
13700051    70 
16700058    70
```

En vez de

```
13700049 75 
13700051 78 
16700058 68 
13700027 70 
13700001 70
```

Comment: No comprendo cuál es el problema. Creo que vendría bien si añades un ejemplo de los datos que vienen en el request, cómo esperas que queden en la DB y cómo están quedando actualmente.

Comment: Este es el array de $sqlStr2 y en ese orden lo ingreso 
13700049,
13700051,
16700058,
13700027,
13700001 

y este es el orden del array $notas: 
75
78
68
70
70


Y este es el orden el que me los inserta:

13700001 75
13700027 78
13700049 68
13700051 70
16700058 70

En vez de 
13700049    75
13700051    78 
16700058    68
13700027    70
13700001    70

Comment: estoy editando tu pregunta para añadir los datos.

Comment: En una vista rápida, no veo nada en tu código que reordene los datos, ¿estás seguro que llegan en ese orden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, tal vez ya hayas solucionado tu problema, pero quizás pueda ayudar a alguien más.Agregando el siguiente código para ver el contenido y el orden de las variables que recibes en de formulario:

```
else if ($_REQUEST["set"] == "insertarCursos") {
print_r($_REQUEST["alumnos"]);
echo"<br/>";
print_r($_REQUEST["notafinal"]);

$alumnos    = explode(",", $_REQUEST["alumnos"]);
```